# What is the meaning of . (dot, period) in additional_dependencies array of pre-commit config?

Tags: pre-commit.com

I came across the following `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/blob/main/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml). It contains the following section:

```yaml
additional_dependencies:
  - .
```

What is the meaning of the dot? Is it necessary?

---

After solution I created PR to remove the unused `.` [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/pull/3327).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case it does nothing, it is a mistake.  I believe an older version of this was selecting specific extras like `.[core]` and this is an artifact of that

`.` is always installed and is the hook repository (in this case ansible-lint)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit